# "Expression is not assignable" in a conditional statement with '?' (In C)

Tags: c, conditional-statements

I just encountered conditional statements with the '?' operator, and can't figure out why the "exit = 1" statement is no assignable. I've tried switching up the type of variable, and throwing in parenthesis.

```
//all the normal stuff is included

unsigned int exit = 0;

      (strcmp(arg2, "%rax") == 0)? r2 = RAX :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%rcx") == 0)? r2 = RCX :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%rdx") == 0)? r2 = RDX :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%rbx") == 0)? r2 = RBX :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%rsp") == 0)? r2 = RSP :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%rbp") == 0)? r2 = RBP :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%rsi") == 0)? r2 = RSI :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%rdi") == 0)? r2 = RDI :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%r8") == 0)? r2 = R8 :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%r9") == 0)? r2 = R9 :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%r10") == 0)? r2 = R10 :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%r11") == 0)? r2 = R11 :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%r12") == 0)? r2 = R12 :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%r13") == 0)? r2 = R13 :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%r14") == 0)? r2 = R14 :
      (strcmp(arg2, "%r15") == 0)? r2 = NO_REG : exit = 1; //Equivalent to "true" in the if() statement
```

The error is showing on the last line, "exit = 1"

Comment: As a side note, this is _horrible_ code both in terms of readability and efficiency. What you should do instead is to put all valid strings in a sorted look-up table. Binary search through that one. If you find a match, use that index as look-up in another table of integers/enums.

Comment: conditional *expressions*.

Comment: the name `exit` is a well known function name: `exit()` that is exposed via the `stdlib.h` header file.  Strongly suggest changing that name

Comment: the posted code does not contain a `if()` statement.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: do NOT use assignment statements in the true/false parameters.  rather use: `r2 = (strcmp(arg2, "%rax") == 0)?  RAX : ... followed by `if( r2 == NO_REG ) { exit = 1; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment has lower precedence than conditional. Thus, `a ? b : c = 0` evaluates as `(a ? b : c) = 0`, where `(a ? b : c)` is not a valid lvalue.

Immediate solution: use parentheses to force the desired parse: `a ? b : (c = 0)`.

Better solution: rewrite into something nicer, like a loop over an array of pairs — or at the very least, an `if`/`else if` structure, which will make precedence a non-issue.

Comment: I agree, this is basically a series of "if() {...} else if() {..." statements disguised as a horrible conditional statement.

Comment: It reminds me of the ["Ternary Operator Nesting Syndrome"](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/Ternary-Operator-Nesting-Syndrome).